# My field validation doesn't seem to work! Did I miss something here?

Tags: c#

I am trying to validate fields so user can't have entered data with empty fields. The problem is that I am still adding empty fields, so my validation isn't working.

First, I am checking is type is selected from a combo box. Then I am checking if which type user picked, and then depending on the type I am checking a fields for empty string before entering a data.

Did I miss something here?

```
private void btnAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Multiple level field validations.
    if (cmbType.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0 && 
            (txtUserName.Text != string.Empty || 
            txtPassword.Text != string.Empty))
        {
            string SQL =
                "INSERT INTO PersonalData([Type], [UserName], [Password]) " +
                "VALUES(@Type, @UserName, @Password)";

            InsertData(SQL);
        }
        else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1 && 
            (txtURL.Text != string.Empty || 
            txtUserName.Text != string.Empty || 
            txtPassword.Text != string.Empty))
        {
            // Creating SQL string. Using [] will prevent any erros
            // that might occur if any other names will be reserved words.
            string SQL =
                "INSERT INTO PersonalData([Type], [URL], [UserName], [Password]) " +
                "VALUES(@Type, @URL, @UserName, @Password)";

            InsertData(SQL);
        }
        else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2 && 
            (txtSoftwareName.Text != string.Empty || 
            txtSerialCode.Text != string.Empty))
        {
            // Creating SQL string. Using [] will prevent any erros
            // that might occur if any other names will be reserved words.
            string SQL =
                "INSERT INTO PersonalData([Type], [SoftwareName], [SerialCode]) " +
                "VALUES(@Type, @SoftwareName, @SerialCode)";

            InsertData(SQL);
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please fill out all required fields!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please select a type first!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a switch statement to test cmbType.SelectedIndex and you should probably be using && instead of || for the field value checks if all fields are required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you want to or the potential fields and not and them?
For instance,

```
else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1 && 
    (txtURL.Text != string.Empty && 
    txtUserName.Text != string.Empty && 
    txtPassword.Text != string.Empty))
```

Will only allow you to insert the data if the url, username and password have a value - using the or's only one of those values needs to be filled in before the insertion is called, meaning you could have a valid url but no password and username entered.

Comment: +1 I think you've nailed it - with his current checks, just one field needs to be non-empty for the code to continue....

Comment: I guess the problem was with my logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text.Trim()) 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text.Trim())
```

Comment: that doesn't account for string of 1 or more spaces

Comment: I like the idea, but I am still adding a value if one field was empty. PS, I am using OR statement '||'.

Comment: Try to format your code so it fits in the SO code window without having to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

A check like this:

```
if(txtUserName.Text != string.Empty)
```

will be passed if your users enter a couple of spaces into `txtUserName`.

You should probably change all your checks to

```
if(txtUserName.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
```

The call to `.Trim()` trims away any trailing spaces, and **then** checks to see if anything is left....

Comment: Well, I don't think the problem is there, but ok. Look at my op.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: right - seems fairly straightforward and no red flags showing up :-) hmm.... do you get the error for **all** different types of choices the user makes? Or just for a few - if so: for which??

Comment: I don't get any errors. I am displaying 'Data was successfully added." which means empty entry passes through my field validation when I leave at least 1 field empty.

Comment: OK,but with your current check, as soon as **at least** one field is non-empty, then you continue on ...... you're not checking to make sure **ALL** fields are non-empty.....

Comment: But wait, what if user has a password including spaces, wouldn't that make the password invalid?

Comment: @HelpNeeder: `.Trim()` only trims off trailing spaces - it doesn't remove spaces from within the string...